# Cross-Domain cookies not accessible by Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, cookies, cross-domain

I have an EXTJS application on http://extjs.domain1.com and serverside Laravel application on http://domain2.com.

I noticed that some browsers (like Safari or old IE) has set very strict cookies privacy settings by default. In the end, if browser don't accept cookies, my laravel_session cookie cannot be saved and the user cannot log in.

My idea is to display a proper information for the user, only if the cookies cant be saved in current browser. So, on my ExtJS's app launch, after it's initialized, I'm sending a custom Ajax GET request to the server (from domain1.com to domain2.com) and the server returns me a Set-Cookie header with sample cookie.
If the cookie is saved, it would mean that the browser's settings are OK (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Now, my cookie's name is Time.
The ajax response in firebug looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2016 12:19:32 GMT

Server: Apache

Set-Cookie: Time=1454511121; expires=Wed, 03-Feb-2016 14:54:11 GMT; Max-Age=9279; path=/; laravel_session=LONG---SESSION---KEY; expires=Wed, 03-Feb-2016 14:19:32 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly

Cache-Control: no-cache

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://extjs.domain1.com

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100

Connection: Keep-Alive

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Type: application/json
```

I have tried many combinations.
Every time the

```
console.log(document.cookie)
```

returns an empty string.

The "Time" cookie is visible in firebug > Cookies and it is NOT httponly.

The "expires" of "Time" is greater than my current browser/computer date.

I tried setting "path" of cookie to '/' or empty string.

I tried setting the "domain" of cookie to ".domain1.com", "extjs.domain1.com".

What am I doing wrong? The document.cookie is always empty, but firefox shows me that there is a non-httponly cookie.

I noticed a little difference in chrome.
The response Set-Cookie looks like this:

```
Set-Cookie:Time=1454511121; expires=Wed, 03-Feb-2016 14:54:11 GMT; Max-Age=7715; path=/;
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=LONG---SESSION---KEY; expires=Wed, 03-Feb-2016 14:45:36 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
```

There are two Set-Cookie headers, but I read that it should not be a problem.

In Chrome I can see the cookies in Dev tools > Network tab > xhr request > Cookies tab. I cannot see a cookie in Dev tools > Resources > Cookies > extjs.domain1.com

Comment: I have the same problem   Finally you found any solution? Thank you so much!

Comment: @AralRoca I'm afraid I didn't fix that in the end...

Comment: I see that if the cookie have `http-only` is not possible to access via javascript. But if you put the flag `withCredentials = true` the cookie automatically is sended in the request